# Json UTF-8 file is wrongly retreived with Tomcat but not with Eclipse

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, tomcat

I run a Java Spring project. For dev purposes, I have an embedded Tomcat in my Eclipse in order to test my development continuously.

I deployed the spring boot app on a VPS where Tomcat 9 is running, and on the VPS I encounter encoding issues when I get a JSON file.

On the VPS if I type in the terminal `root@vps:~# curl --cookie "lang=fr"  localhost:8080/utils` I get

```
{signout: "Se déconnecter"}
```

On my computer, with Firefox if I type in the address bar `localhost:8080/utils` (it targets tomcat embedded in Eclipse), I get

```
{signout: "Se déconnecter"}
```

But on my computer, with the same Firefox if I type in the address bar `my.vps.ip:8080/utils` I get

```
{signout: "Se dÃ©connecter"}
```

The controller function is

```
@RequestMapping("/utils")
public String getUtils(@CookieValue(defaultValue = "en", value = "lang", required = false) String languageCode) {
    if (!languageService.exists(languageCode)) {
        languageCode = "en";
    }
    return String.format("/msg/%s/displayedWords.js", languageCode);
}
```

I tried to add `URIEncoding="UTF-8"` to the `Connector` definition on Tomcat file `/etc/tomcat/server.xml` but nothing changed.

What could be wrong?
Thanks

### EDIT

The locale on the VPS:

```
root@vps:~# locale
LANG=C.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="C.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=C.UTF-8
LC_TIME=C.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=C.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="C.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=C.UTF-8
LC_NAME=C.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=C.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=C.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=C.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=C.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: What locale setting is your VPS using?

Comment: Hello @nitind I answered your question in the post

Comment: Thank you. What are the headers for the request that you're sending?

Comment: I think that's just a list of all _available_ locales. Not the one which is currently in use?

Comment: @andrewjames sorry I edited the anwer with the locale command result.

Comment: @nitind I just enter in the address bar of Firefox the URL and get the JSON as a result

Comment: How are you starting Tomcat? I recommend using a [`setenv.sh` file](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/RUNNING.txt) (or `setenv.bat` on Windows) in which you set `JAVA_OPTS` to include this option: `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`. This sets the [default encoding of the JVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361975/setting-the-default-java-character-encoding) in which Tomcat will run. (There may be other points along the way where your data is not being handled as UTF-8 - like the headers mentioned in an earlier comment.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I ended up by replacing all the special characters by their unicode code, my file became:

```
{signout: "Se d\u00E9connecter"}
```